# Moving file to another computer

Tags: c#, security, file, networking

I have prblem with my C# application. I need to move file to my server, but my server is secured with user name and password. Way is like this:

```
\\Server\Folder
```

And code is this:

```
...
File.Move(args[0], "\\\\Server\\Folder");
...
```

How can I move file there? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use impersonation:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsIdentity idnt = new WindowsIdentity(username, password);
WindowsImpersonationContext context = idnt.Impersonate();

File.Move(args[0], "\\\\Server\\Folder");

context.Undo();
```

Comment: If the above doesn't work, try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ConnectUNCPathCredentials.aspx).

Comment: If it's a linux server with Windows file sharing enabled (Samba), this should work.  If not you might try something like an FTP solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could P\Invoke the Windows API function `WNetAddConnection2` to connect to the share before copying.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is the PInvoke page: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/WNetAddConnection2.html

[DllImport("Mpr.dll", EntryPoint="WNetAddConnection2", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private static extern ErrorCodes WNetAddConnection2(NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,ref string lpPassword,ref 
                            string lpUsername, System.UInt32 dwFlags );